# alert() doesn't pop up

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to pop up an alert and I'm using the Visual Studio to run it on my Firefox. I've been at it for sometime now and I simply can't figure out what the mistake is.

Snippet of my code:

```html
<div class="widget-Sidebar">
    <div class="header green">
        <h1 class="title">Recent Reports</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-blank">
        <div class="recent_reports">
            <div class="row">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="title">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="oneDay" class="reportresponsecheck" />&nbsp;&nbsp;One Day
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

(the rest of the html code is fine and there are no errors with this)

My js code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.reportresponsecheck').click(function () {
        alert("11");
        var isreportchecked = $("#chkReports").is(":checked");
        var isresponsechecked = $("#chkResponses").is(":checked");
        var isonedaychecked = $("#oneDay").is(":checked");
        alert(isonedaychecked);
        CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please tell me if I need to provide more details.

Comment: the first alert or the second alert not show?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#, please make sure only to use appropriate tags. I've moved the `c#` tag.

Comment: Did you add any `version` of `jquery`?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar: Nope. Since the existing code was running fine, I didn't think I'd have to.

Comment: Use `console.log()` for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Both alerts are working fine. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.reportresponsecheck').change(function () {
    alert("11");
    var isreportchecked = $("#chkReports").is(":checked");
    var isresponsechecked = $("#chkResponses").is(":checked");
    var isonedaychecked = $("#oneDay").is(":checked");
    alert(isonedaychecked);
    CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/W6jAj/)**

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the Question. I missed the brackets.

Comment: @PR: Updated answer with demo fiddle bro :)

Answer (score 1):

There was syntax error in your code . Try this

```
<div class="widget-Sidebar">
                    <div class="header green">
                        <h1 class="title">Recent Reports</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-blank">
                        <div class="recent_reports">
                            <div class="row">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="title">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="oneDay" class="reportresponsecheck"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;One Day
                                            </div>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                   </table>
                                    </div>
                                     </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

                                      <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.reportresponsecheck').click(function () {
    alert("11");
    var isreportchecked = $("#chkReports").is(":checked");
    var isresponsechecked = $("#chkResponses").is(":checked");
    var isonedaychecked = $("#oneDay").is(":checked");
    alert(isonedaychecked);
    CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);
});
});//added
                                      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `)` at line `CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);});`

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.reportresponsecheck').click(function () {
alert("11");
var isreportchecked = $("#chkReports").is(":checked");
var isresponsechecked = $("#chkResponses").is(":checked");
var isonedaychecked = $("#oneDay").is(":checked");
alert(isonedaychecked);
CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed it in the question. The code compiles fine.

Comment: FYI : To test javascript. Copy the code and past to javascript part of http://jsfiddle.net/ Then click on JsHint button to validate

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this ");"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.reportresponsecheck').click(function () {
alert("11");
var isreportchecked = $("#chkReports").is(":checked");
var isresponsechecked = $("#chkResponses").is(":checked");
var isonedaychecked = $("#oneDay").is(":checked");
alert(isonedaychecked);
CheckUnchekReportResponse(isreportchecked, isresponsechecked);});
});
```